# Erlang applications design (how to short-circuit)

Tags: erlang

I am having an existential question about how I design my erlang applications:

I usually create an application, which starts a supervisor and some workers. 
Aside from the supervision tree, I have modules with functions (duh).
I also have a web API that calls functions from applications' modules.
When I stop my application (`application:stop(foo).`), the webserver can still call `foo`'s functions.

I find it "not idiomatic" to not be able to have a proper circuit-breaker for the `foo` application.

Does it mean that every public functions from `foo` should spawn a process under it's supervisor?

Thanks,
Bastien

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily, for two reasons:

The `foo` application will have two kinds of functions: those that require the worker processes to be running, and those that don't (most likely pure functions).  If the application is stopped, obviously the former will fail when called, while the latter will still work.  As per Erlang's "let it crash" philosophy, this is just another error condition that the web server needs to handle (or not handle).  If the pure functions still work, there is no reason to prohibit the web server from calling them: it means that a greater portion of the system is functional.

In an Erlang node, stopping an application is not something you'd normally do.  An Erlang application declares dependencies, that is, applications that need to be running for it to function correctly.  You'll notice that if you try to start an application before its dependencies, it will refuse to start.  While it's possible to stop applications manually, this means that the state of the node is no longer in accordance with the assumptions of the application model.  When building a "release" consisting of a set of Erlang applications, normally they would all be started as `permanent` applications, meaning that if any one application crashes, the entire Erlang node would exit, in order not to violate this assumption.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. I understand now that I was being paranoid about something that is not a real use-case.